# Receiving timeout from ET_SentEvent object when filtering by EventDate

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, c#

I'm using the ET_SentEvent object to get data after a particular date and the only field I can see that is of any use in this object for filtering by date is the 'EventDate' field.

I've written this code:

```
public void GetSentTracking()
{
    ET_SentEvent sentevent = new ET_SentEvent { AuthStub = Client };

    DateTime filterDate = new DateTime(2015, 11, 1, 13, 0, 0);

    sentevent.SearchFilter = new SimpleFilterPart()
    {
        Property = "EventDate",
        SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.greaterThan,
        DateValue = new DateTime[] { filterDate }
    };

    try
    {
        var results = sentevent.Get();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

When running this code it always times out and doesn't give any useful information on what to do.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default timeout for a request through the FuelSDK that uses SOAP (which SentEvent does) is 2 minutes. If you need longer then it would require updating the ET_Client.cs file so that when SoapClient is instantiated, the timeout property would need to be set to a value greater than 2 minutes.

Comment: That's really useful to know, thank you. So I'm guessing that I must be requesting too much information to retrieve within that time limit. I had imagined that the property 'EventDate' that I was filtering by was somehow broken and causing a server error.

Comment: A large volume of data would be my guess as well.  Even though there are a max of 2500 records coming back per request, it has to sort them so it can take some time, typically the follow-up calls for the next batch of 2500 goes a bit quicker than the first.